# Return from function is changing output values

Tags: r

I am building (what I thought to be) a simple loop that builds a dataframe of boxcox parameters - lambda and shift. The code seemed to work, but when I wanted to turn it into a function, I noticed that R was duplicating my output values.

Reproducible code below, hopefully someone more knowledgeable can explain this very confusing behavior.

```
#Just running the code
library(MASS)
x <- iris[,-5]
bc_ref <- data.frame(var = character(),
                     pwr = numeric(),
                     shift = numeric())
for(i in 1:ncol(x)){
  tmp <- x[,i]
  orig <- colnames(x)[i]
  if(min(tmp) < 0){
    tmp <- tmp + abs(min(tmp)*1.1)
    shift <- abs(min(tmp))
  }
  bcMod <- boxcox(lm(as.matrix(tmp)~1), 
                  lambda = seq(-2.01, 2.01, 1/10),
                  plotit = F)

  lambda <- bcMod$x[which.max(bcMod$y)]
  if(lambda == 0){
    stop("Error, lambda is 0")
  }
  bc_row <- data.frame(var = paste0("bc.",orig),
                       pwr = signif(lambda),
                       shift = ifelse(
                         exists("shift"), 
                         shift, 
                         NA))
  bc_ref <- rbind(bc_ref, bc_row)
  if(exists("shift")){
    rm(shift)
  }
} #End loop 

#bc_ref
              var   pwr shift
1 bc.Sepal.Length -0.11    NA
2  bc.Sepal.Width  0.29    NA
3 bc.Petal.Length  0.89    NA
4  bc.Petal.Width  0.69    NA
```

Above is how the function ought to work, below shows the exact same code placed into a function. Suddenly the output changes!

The last value in bc_ref$pwr is duplicated. Why is it just that one column? I'm really struggling to understand why this is happening.

```
fxn <- function(x){

  bc_ref <- data.frame(var = character(),
                       pwr = numeric(),
                       shift = numeric())
  for(i in 1:ncol(x)){
    tmp <- x[,i]
    orig <- colnames(x)[i]
    if(min(tmp) < 0){
      tmp <- tmp + abs(min(tmp)*1.1)
      shift <- abs(min(tmp))
    }
    bcMod <- boxcox(lm(as.matrix(tmp)~1), 
                    lambda = seq(-2.01, 2.01, 1/10),
                    plotit = F)

    lambda <- bcMod$x[which.max(bcMod$y)]
    if(lambda == 0){
      stop("Error, lambda is 0")
    }
    bc_row <- data.frame(var = paste0("bc.",orig),
                         pwr = signif(lambda),
                         shift = ifelse(
                           exists("shift"), 
                           shift, 
                           NA))
    bc_ref <- rbind(bc_ref, bc_row)
    if(exists("shift")){
      rm(shift)
    }
  } #End loop
  return(bc_ref)
}
#fxn(x)
              var  pwr shift
1 bc.Sepal.Length 0.69    NA
2  bc.Sepal.Width 0.69    NA
3 bc.Petal.Length 0.69    NA
4  bc.Petal.Width 0.69    NA
```

Thank you for you time!

Comment: Your code currently runs with errors:  "object 'out' not found".  In addition, you should put `MASS::boxcox()` or `library(MASS)` when using a function like `boxcox` that is not search path for most of us.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, 'out' was something I forgot to remove. Likewise, library(MASS) was left out. I will fix that right now, thank you!

Comment: If I do `library(MASS)`, load your function, and then run `fxn(iris[,-5])`, I get this error:   "Error in as.matrix(tmp) : object 'tmp' not found".  If you want help here, you're going to need to provide working code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the solution is to change this:

```
lm(as.matrix(tmp)~1)
```

to this

```
tmp~1
```

Comment: Strange! Wish I knew the reason. Thanks for giving it some thought. I'll spend more time on my example code in the future.